# PHP array_search with associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I've an array's

first one:

```
    [0] => 0289 [1] => 0146 [2] => 5519 [3] => 5308 [4] => 5503 [5] => 5357
```

second one(associative):

```
    [78941] => 5308 [15749] => 5519 [1469156] => 5308 [78971413] => 5357 [418979] => 0289
```

Need to find keys in second one by first one value. One by one. I did some loop:

```
for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
$keys=array_search($first_array[$i],$second_array);   
file_put_contents('check.txt',$keys,FILE_APPEND);
}
```

But get nothing. What I'am doing wrong?

```
Addition
```

The second array is more large than I show here, approximately 10000 values.

I must insert 5 values per file and these values must be uniq, to avoid overlap.

It will be looks like :

```
  $t=0;
 for($i=0;$i<=count($second_array);$i++){

$keys=array_search($first_array[$t],$second_array);   
file_put_contents('check.txt',$keys,FILE_APPEND);
 $t++
 if ($t==5){$t=0}

}
```

Hope it would help.

Comment: Your code has no errors as it is. Does the program have permissions to create the file or write in it? What does "getting nothing" mean?

Comment: Thank for answer. File is creating. But there is really nothing in it) I'll check the solutions provided. And reply soon.

Comment: Try to isolate the problem into an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). If I copy your code as it is into a .php file and run it, a file called `check.txt` is created and it contains a sequence of numbers that correspond to the indices that `array_search` finds, so the real problem is probably somewhere else. For example, maybe the user that you use to run PHP does not have write permission to the file.

Comment: Thanx for your attention. But I see just empty array "Array()" in file.

Comment: That cannot happen with the code you have shown: `array_search` returns a single value, not an array, so single values are written to the file. If you really are using this code and find `Array()` in the file, something else is writing over the file afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

If you need only keys, so just filter them:

```
$keys = array_intersect($first, array_keys($second));
```

However, if you want to get both values and keys, then it'll be like:

```
$keysAndValues = array_intersect_key($second, array_flip($first));
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. But I have some different task. I don't need all values be added to array(or written to file) at once. Need to find and write to file(or add to array) one by one. I mean first "0289" -> write to file and delete from existing one, then "0146" and etc. If I had several values like in example "5308", need to find first one, write to file, delete from existing and then loop must go again in same sequence.

Comment: Note: second array will be more large than in example, but first one will be as it seen here.

Comment: @Sam then provide your logic and samples in question

Comment: Still can't get - why finding full intersection & writing it then in one piece to your file isn't a solution?

Comment: If sequence in $keys will be like: 1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5 (by $first_array value). Then it will solution for me :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it much simple way using **foreach** loop

```
<?php
      $i = 0;
      foreach($array2 as $key => $value):
         if($array1[$i] == $value) {
           //$key is the required key, manage your stuffs here.
         }
         $i++;
      endforeach;
 ?>
```

Comment: This is more efficient than my suggestion. Use this.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($first_array as $first_key => $first_value){
    foreach($second_array as $second_key => $second_value){
        if($first_value == $second_value){
            file_put_contents($file_name, $second_key . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agreed. @nurakantech has a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

`array_search()` returns the key if it finds the value, and returns false if not found, so if

you want keys, this code is what you want:

```
$one=array("0"=>"0146","1"=>"5519","2"=>"5308","3"=>"5503","4"=>"5357");
$two=array("78941"=>"5308","15749"=>"5519","1469156"=>"5308","78971413"=>"5357","418979"=>"5357");
$result=array();

for($i=0;$i<=5;$i++){
if(array_search($one[$i],$two))
$result[]=array_search($one[$i],$two);
}
print_r($result);//OR file_put_contents('check.txt',$result,FILE_APPEND)
```